# How to add a new column to a data frame that is the -ln of the variable "hr" if the two "age" variables in the two dfs match in R?

Tags: r, variables, new-operator

My goal is to create a new column "HoLj" in df1 that is the -ln of "hr" from df2 if the corresponding age in df1, matches the age2 in df2.

```
df1<- data.frame(age = c("1","2","4","5","7","8"), dif = c("y", "n", "y", "n","n","y")

df2<- data.frame(age2=c("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8"),hr=c(56, 57, 23, 46, 45, 19, 21, 79)
```

My goals is to create a new column in df1 that looks like below:

```
age   dif    hoLj
1      y      -ln(56)
2      n      -ln(57)
4      y      -ln(46)
5      n      -ln(45)
7      n      -ln(21)
8      y      -ln(79)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do a join and then get the natural log

```
library(dplyr)
left_join(df1, df2) %>%
     mutate(hoLj = -log(hr)) %>%
     select(-hr)
```

---

Or with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[df2, hoLj := -log(hr), on = .(age)]
df1
#   age dif      hoLj
#1:   1   y -4.025352
#2:   2   n -4.043051
#3:   4   y -3.828641
#4:   5   n -3.806662
#5:   7   n -3.044522
#6:   8   y -4.369448
```

Comment: Thank you! what if the name of "age" in df2 is not the same as df1. Like maybe "age2"?

Comment: @TongClaireXu No issue, just use `by = c('age' = 'age2')` in the `left_join` and in second case, `on = .(age = age2)`

Comment: I got the error message below:`setDT(dft1)[dft2, hoLj := -log(hr), on = .(age=age2)]
Error in Math.factor(hr) : ‘log’ not meaningful for factors`

Comment: @TongClaireXu that is only because you must have created the 'hr' as `character` and with `stringsAsFactors = TRUE` by default, it would be a factor.  Please change your column 'hr to 'numeric. i.e. `dft2$hr <- as.numeric(as.character(dft2$hr))`

Comment: I got it.thanks! In the same token, if my df2 is renamed to 'population1', hr is "white__1" `> setDT(df1)[population1, HoLj := -log(white__1), on = .(age = age2)]
Error in `[.data.table`(setDT(df1), population1, `:=`(HoLj, -log(white__1)),  : 
  logical error. i is not a data.table, but 'on' argument is provided.` What could be the issue here? thanks!

Comment: @TongClaireXu sorry, I showed the solutions for the examples you provided and it is working.  Here,your error seems to be that one of them is not data.table.  So please convert to that

Comment: Thank you for all your help!